# Can I run Python 3.3+ on Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, python

It seems like Raspbian Wheezy does not support Python 3.3, only 3.2.

Can I run Python 3.3+ on Raspbian Jessie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google for '[raspbian jessie python version](http://tinyurl.com/ngbet48)' gets me to [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/JessieRoadmap) which clearly states:

> **Python 3.4 support**
>
> ```
> Python 3.4 is the default and only Python 3 version in Jessie
> ```

So your answer is **YES**